# Login with google

Tags: codeigniter, gmail-api

Currently, I m working on login with google in codeignitor.

I set all the client keys with my project and turn the testing mode on in auth content screen.
but there is an error like.

[image]

How can I set testing user mode on? I attached image

[image]

please help me out of here.

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down a little you will see a button called add test users.  This will allow you to add users who will be allowed to test your app.

[image]

Correction to your title:

This is not login (authencation) this is Oauth2 (Authorization).

Comment: I already add a test user and try to log in with test user email but not work